# Leveling subfloor

Tags: flooring

We have older home with an addition. The addition was put in an inch higher than original floors. We are going to put in vinyl plank flooring throughout but need to transition these heights. Ideas?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need a lot more info to help, e.g. a picture or two of the transition, and perhaps a plan showing the floor construction for the main house and the addition.

Comment: Differences in floor height like the one you explain are often due to some sort of construction aspect that prevented alignment (as opposed to a deliberate architectural design aspect). Have you any notion as to why the height difference exists/? Could it merely be the addition of a floor cover treatment that was added?

Comment: What is the composition of each floor system? (I.e.: old floor is carpet on 1/2” boards on 1 1/2” boards on floor joists at 16” on center AND new floor is 1/2” OSB board on 3/4” plywood on floor joists at 24” on center.) Something like that would help.

Comment: The new addition which was added,dining room and master bedroom, was an accident by contractor. Did not match height to kitchen existing flooring. We have carpet with a transition under it. Not good enough to lay flooring over. The old floor is on 12 inch centers with tongue and grove and 1/2 OSB board.(100 year old). New floor is on 16 inch center with 3/4 inch OSB.